# Solve $y^3~dx+2(x^2-xy^2)~dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is a general method for solving equations of this type:$$y^3~dx+2(x^2-xy^2)~dy=0$$
Supposedly it should be solvable via substitution $y=ux^{\alpha}$ where $u$ is a function of $x$ but I wasn't able to find $\alpha$ that produces separable differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you could start by writing your ODE in the following form:
$$\frac{dx(y)}{dy}-\frac{2}{y}\cdot x(y)=-\frac{2}{y^3}\cdot x(y)^2 \tag{1}$$
This is clearly a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation), where $y$ is the independent variable, and $x$ is the dependent variable.

---

Hence, one can use the well-known change of variable $v(y)=x(y)^{1-2}=\dfrac{1}{x(y)}$ to convert $(1)$ into a linear non-homogeneous ODE.
$$\color{green}{-\frac{1}{x(y)^2}\cdot \frac{dx(y)}{dy}}+\color{blue}{\frac{2}{y}\cdot \frac{1}{x(y)}}=\frac{2}{y^3}$$
$$\color{green}{\frac{dv(y)}{dy}}+\color{blue}{\frac{2}{y}\cdot v(y)}=\frac{2}{y^3} \tag{2}$$
There are many ways to solve linear non-homogeneous ODE's, such as [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First_order_equation) or using [Laplace Transforms](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx). I will use the [integrating factor method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx), which is likely the easiest one in your case.

---

One can easily show that for this case, the integrating factor is $\mu(y)=y^2$. We now multiply equation $(2)$ by $\mu(y)$ on both sides:
$$y^2\frac{dv}{dy}+2yv=\frac{2}{y}$$
$$y^2v'+(y^2)'v=\frac{2}{y}$$
As a consequence to multiplying our ODE with $\mu(y)$, we notice that the LHS is a specific case of the product rule. Hence, we can apply the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) *in reverse*.
$$(y^2 v)'=\frac{2}{y}$$
All that remains to do is to integrate both sides with respect to $y$ and  substitute back $v=\dfrac{1}{x}$ to obtain an explicit solution for $x(y)$. Getting an explicit solution for $y(x)$ is possible, though one would have to make use of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).